# Upgrade data script of custom extension in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, upgrade

Can we upgrade data script of custom extension in Magento without changing the version number in config.xml of extension?

I have created extenstion in Magento.

```
<Pb_gsp>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
</Pb_gsp>
```

Now, I want to add new column in my table. I know that we can do this by changing the version number in config.xml and create new sql file `mysql4-upgrade-1.1.1-1.1.2.sql` .

But I don't want to change the version number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by executing a custom query in Magento, using the core resource model. check the below code

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');    
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = $resource->getTableName('your/extension');
$query = "Alter your table"
$writeConnection->query($query);
```

But I don't think this a proper way of executing custom query. Hope this will help you some how.

Comment: Then you need write a custom script for that, create a file get the content from local.xml read the mysql config and the fire an alter query.